# Scipy minimize returns an array too big

Tags: python, memory, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to minimize this function but using scipy minimize i expect to get in return an array of the same size of the one in input, that is (92445,) but i get an array of size (92445, 92445) and so i get the following error:

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 63.7 GiB for an array with shape (92445, 92445) and data type float64

I don't understant if i simply did not really understand how minimize works or if there is another problem that i don't see

```
X = np.asarray(freezer.dropna())
Xc = X
D = np.random.random((5,18489))
Z = np.random.random((5,5))
B = np.ones((5,5))
u = 0.5
us = np.sqrt(u)
l = 0.1

def P1(Di):
    Di = Di.reshape(D.shape)
    A = Z - np.matmul(Di,Xc) - B
    return (np.linalg.norm(A, 'fro'))**2

def P2(Xi):
    Xi = Xi.reshape(Xc.shape)
    A1 = np.vstack(X, us*(Z-B))
    A2 = np.vstack(np.identity(18489), us*D)
    A3 = np.matmul(A2, Xi)
    A4 = A1 - A3
    return (np.linalg.norm(A4, 'fro'))**2

def P3(Z):
    Z = Z.reshape(Z.shape)
    A = Z - np.matmul(D, Xc) - B
    return (np.linalg.norm(A, 'fro'))**2 + (l/u)*np.linalg.norm(Z, 1)

Df = D.flatten()
Df = minimize(P1, Df)
D = Df.reshape(D.shape)

Xcf = Xc.flatten()
Xcf = minimize(P2, Xcf)
Xc = Xcf.reshape(Xc.shape)

Zf = Z.flatten()
Zf = minimize(P3, Zf)
Z = Zf.reshape(Z.shape)

B = Z - np.matmul(D,Xc) - B
```

Comment: As, I know this is because your hardware is not capable of this execution. And as I remember MemoryError: Unable to allocate 63.7 GiB means that you need an avaliable ram (not just total ram) of higher than 63.7 GB

Comment: That assumes that OP actually _wants_ an array of shape 92000x92000, but it really sounds like they don't. The hardware is not an issue.

Comment: Exactly where do you get this error?  Full error message.

Comment: The `(92445, 92445)` shape suggests that some step is trying to `broadcast` something like a `(92445,)` with a `(1, 92445)`.  Keep careful track of shapes, and pay attention to where this error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Nonlinear approach

For the case of P1, you can notice that the argument D only affects one row of A at a time. Therefore, you can optimize each row of D separately, and combine them at the end into a single D matrix. Solving a 18489 dimension problem five times is much easier than solving a 92445 dimension problem, so this will make it faster and use less memory.

I also found that it was necessary to use [L-BFGS-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS), a solver that uses less memory than what you are currently using, BFGS.

Code:

```
def P1(Di):
    Di = Di.reshape(D.shape)
    A = Z - np.matmul(Di,Xc) - B
    return (np.linalg.norm(A, 'fro'))**2


def P1_simplified(Di, idx):
    """A version of P1 which operates on only one row of D,
    one row of Z, and one row of B."""
    Di = Di.reshape((1,) + (D.shape[1],))
    A = Z[idx] - np.matmul(Di,Xc) - B[idx]
    return (np.linalg.norm(A, 'fro'))**2


def solve_P1(D):
    idx=0
    D_list = []
    for idx in range(D.shape[0]):
        print(f"solving row {idx}")
        result = minimize(
            P1_simplified,
            D[idx],
            args=(idx,),
            method='L-BFGS-B',
            options=dict(maxfun=1e7),
        )
        D_row = result.x
        D_list.append(D_row)
    D = np.array(D_list)
    print(f"solution has frobenius norm {P1(D)}")

solve_P1(D)
```

This is sufficient to solve this problem in under a gigabyte of memory, to get a Frobenius norm of ~10^-9. Since 0 is the best possible result, this is pretty close.

I think a similar approach could be used for P2 and P3, though I haven't worked through it in detail.

#### Linear approach

Another approach, which would be way faster, would be to reformat the problem into a linear regression.

Here is a short sketch of a proof.

Taking the square of the Frobenius norm is equivalent to the sum of squares of each element of A. Since `A = Z - np.matmul(Di,Xc) - B`, this is equivalent to minimizing the square of the difference `np.matmul(Di,Xc) - (Z - B)`. Split this into two pieces. Let `Y = (Z - B)`. In order to do a standard linear regression, the parameters must be on the right, and in the expression `np.matmul(Di,Xc)`, they are on the left. Fix this by transposing the inputs and swapping them to get `np.matmul(Xc.T, Di.T)`. We also need to transpose Y as well, so `Y = (Z - B).T`. We are now trying to find `np.matmul(Xc.T, Di.T) ~ Y`. This is now an ordinary least squares problem, and we can use `lstsq()`, which is much faster than minimize.

Code:

```
def P1_lstsq(X, Z, B):
    Y = (Z - B).T
    Di, residuals, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(Xc.T, Y, rcond=None)
    return Di.T

Di = P1_lstsq(X, Z, B)
P1(Di)
```

Not only can this solve the problem in under a millisecond, it also finds a smaller result than the `minimize()` solution.

I think you could apply this to P2 and P3 as well. P3 looks to be equivalent to P1 except with the addition of an intercept to the linear regression. I don't quite understand P2, but since A2 and A3 are constant with respect to Xi, I think you could do something similar.